# Synopsys detect: Request failed authorization [HTTP Error]: There was a problem trying to GET

Tags: maven

when I try to scan a maven-based project with Synopsys detect (https://blackducksoftware.github.io/synopsys-detect/latest/), everything works fine. I get a report in blackduck, but at the end it gives me the following error:

```
com.synopsys.integration.blackduck.exception.BlackDuckApiException: Request failed authorization [HTTP Error]: There was a problem trying to GET https://example.com/api/codelocations?limit=100&q=name%3Aprjojectname%2F2.1.0-SNAPSHOT+maven%2Fbom&offset=0, response was 403 Forbidden.
```

Does anyone know where this comes from? Lack of permissions? I have the following roles associated with my account:

- BOM Manager
- Policy Violation Reviewer
- Project Code Scanner
- Project Manager
- Security Manager

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Check this out. This may be due to not having correct permissions.[Detect run failed: Request failed authorization](https://community.synopsys.com/s/article/Detect-run-failed-Request-failed-authorization-HTTP-Error-There-was-a-problem-trying-to-POST-https-app-blackduck-com-api-projects-response-was-403-Forbidden)